# Could one modify S^1=U(1) to move the Earth under group multiplication?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, rotations

The easiest way (to my humble understanding) to think about the group $\Bbb S^1$ is to consider the set of all complex numbers $z=a+bi$, for which $a^2 + b^2=1$ and use multiplicative operation to construct group of the rotations of the plane, the simplest torus $\Bbb S^1$.

I was wondering if there is any neat way to modify this approach and introduce a group structure for the orbit of the earth, which is an ellipse (if it has not recently changed).

Namely, could we put a group structure on an ellipse by some modifications of the method above? Even if it demands working in another geometry!

I know that the existence of two-square identity is a fundamental fact in this construction. So, probably one should get it fixed for the generalization, if there is any. For instance, stretching or compressing size of the distance of the points on the orbit to the closer focus is the most naive idea that may come to mind. However, looking at the fundamental geometrical property of an ellipse (the fact that sum of distances of each point to the focuses is a constant) might be slightly more interesting.

I would appreciate clear ideas and references you might know for studying about this question.

Comment: You can choose a fixed point $A$ and define $X\times Y$ as the point where the earth will be after $u+v$ seconds from $A$, where $u$ is the time $AX$ and $v$ the time $AY$, for example.

Comment: Just imagine a concentric circle sitting (or outside) the ellipse. To multiply two points on the ellipse, first project onto the circle, multiply there, and then project back.

Comment: Also, see http://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/EllipseMultiplication.shtml

Comment: For posterity, here are two other nice references: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/40378668?sid=21105939639203&uid=2134&uid=70&uid=3739256&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739576 and http://www.ias.ac.in/resonance/Volumes/13/10/0916-0928.pdf

Comment: An ellipse *is* a circle after an appropriate change of coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the nice and illuminating comments you left on my question.
To my understanding, they share the same idea behind, which I thought about and even alluded to that in my question- Stretching or compressing the distance to match the current situation with the previous case. And, your nice comments showed me how to do that.
Moreover, many thanks for the materials for reading more about the extended version of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily construct a bijection (of sets) between $S^1$ and an ellipse, call it $E$. Once you have this bijection $\phi: E \to S^1$ put the following group structure on the ellipse:

$$a b = \phi^{-1}(\phi(a) \phi(b))$$

where you are taking the multiplication $\phi(a) \phi(b)$ in the circle. Basically what you are doing is going from the ellipse to the circle to multiply and then coming back to the ellipse.

Comment: Thanks for putting the idea in a clear statement. That was very helpful.

Comment: No bother, mate. Let me just remark that you can play the same game in general. Given a set $S$, a group $G$ and a bijection $\phi: S \to G$ the same formula will give you a group on $S$.

Comment: Nice supplementary comment. Thanks.
Yes, That's a very good approach to keep in mind, when one is working with a given set, not very well-studied, but in bijection with an algebraic structure.

Comment: @Kaveh: of course the ellipse *is* "very well-studied."

Comment: @symplectomorphic, Yes, I agree that in this case ellipse has been studied since ancient Greece. my last comment was regarding the supplementary comment of "equin" on his answer, in which he pointed out that even for an arbitrary given set $X$, in a set bijection with a group, the method used above still works.
Furthermore, I still imagine regardless of the rich mathematical literature on ellipse, working with a circle is more comfortable and the bijection you illustrated is a living example for this humble claim.